CSP Nonces in Angular 18 and .NET 8 on IIS v. 10 gets net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 (OK)
I have an Angular 18 app with .NET 8 running on IIS that is hosted in AWS. The IIS is Version 10.0.17763.1 and the server hosting it is Windows Server 2019, Version 1809. I have implemented Nonces for Content-Security-Policy. The app works fine on IIS Express when run in Visual Studio 2022, but returns an error when run in the above-mentioned IIS.
I am using both styles of implementation of nonces described in the Angular documentation. I have used ChatGPT for some help.
Here is the error: GET https://[my domain].[my sandbox].com/ net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 (OK).
The angular app does not appear able to launch at all. No angular views are served.
The Nonce is injected correctly into the index.html file.
I have tried various configs and various settings on IIS.
Can any help with either a solution or some advice on steps I could take to get a better idea of the cause of the problem? Thanks.
Here is the relevant part of the CspNonceMiddleware:
     public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Generate the nonce
        string nonce = GenerateNonce();
        context.Items["csp-nonce"] = nonce;

        // Only process HTML responses
        context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
        {
            if (context.Response.ContentType?.Contains("text/html") == true)
            {
                // Remove existing CSP header if present
                if (context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Content-Security-Policy"))
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Security-Policy");
                }

                // Add CSP header with the nonce
                context.Response.Headers.Append("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:; connect-src https: http: data: wss: ws:; frame-src https:; script-src-elem 'self' 'nonce-{nonce}'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-{nonce}'; style-src-elem 'self' 'nonce-{nonce}'; style-src 'self' 'nonce-{nonce}';");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });

        // Intercept the response to inject the nonce into index.html
        var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;
        using (var newBodyStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.Response.Body = newBodyStream;

            // Call the next middleware
            await _next(context);

            // Reset the stream position to read it
            newBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string responseBody = new StreamReader(newBodyStream).ReadToEnd();

            // Replace the placeholder in index.html with the nonce
            responseBody = responseBody.Replace("{nonce}", nonce);

            // Write the updated response back
            context.Response.Body = originalBodyStream;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(responseBody);
        }
    }

        private string GenerateNonce()
        {
            var bytes = new byte[16];
            RandomNumberGenerator.Fill(bytes); // Generate a secure random nonce
            return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }
        

Here is where the CSP_NONCE token is provided. Not that this is located in main.ts, not app.module.ts. I tried it in app.module.ts also, with no success.
export function getCspNonce(): string | null
{
    const meta = document.querySelector('meta[name="csp-nonce"]');
    return meta ? meta.getAttribute('content') : null;
}
        
const providers: Array<StaticProvider> = [
    { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl, deps: [] },
    { provide: 'API_URL', useFactory: getApiUrl, deps: [] },
    { provide: 'COPYRIGHT_FULL', useFactory: getCopyRightFull, deps: [] },
    { provide: 'COPYRIGHT', useValue: legalJson.copyright, deps: [] },
    { provide: 'UI_VERSION', useValue: packageJson.version, deps: [] },
    { provide: CSP_NONCE, useFactory: getCspNonce }


];

console.log(`Checking API server...`);
const apiurl = getApiUrl() + "test" + "?fromUI=true";

fetch(apiurl)
    .then(response => 
    {
        if (!response.ok) 
        {
            // Handle HTTP error responses
         [Checks for servers, edited out for brevity...]

        }
        console.log(`API server is available.`);

        // Continue with normal execution if the response is okay
        platformBrowserDynamic(providers)
            .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
    })
    .catch(error => 
    {
        // Handle network errors or errors thrown from the response status checks
        const img = document.getElementsByClassName('logo-img')[0];
        img?.remove();

        const h3 = document.getElementsByClassName('loading-text')[0];
        h3.innerHTML = error.message || "An error occurred while connecting to the API server.";
    });

        

Here is my startup.configure() method:
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.EnvironmentName.Equals("Development"))
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

[Tried app.UseMiddleware here...]

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

[Tried app.UseMiddleware here...]
        app.UseStaticFiles();


[Tried app.UseMiddleware here...]
        // Turned off browser check on 11/18/2023
        //app.UseSupportedBrowserMiddleware();



        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

      [Tried app.UseMiddleware here...]
  app.UseMiddleware<CspNonceMiddleware>();


        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.EnvironmentName.Equals("Development"))
            {
                spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 480);
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }

Here is the Index.html file. This one gets served, and the nonces are set; it is the angular views afterward that are not loading:

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!--x out localrefs and un-x server refs as needed to speed up dev.
        Server refs are faster and can be used if not debugging api or auth-->
    <title>MHK MarketProminence DEV</title>
    <base apiref="https://localhost:44378/"
          authref="https://localhost:44322/"
        
          href="/">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="csp-nonce" content=""/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' ; base-uri 'self' ; form-action 'self' ; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:; connect-src https: http: data: wss: ws:; frame-src https:; script-src-elem 'self' 'nonce-{nonce}' ; script-src 'self' 'nonce-{nonce}' ; style-src-elem 'self' 'nonce-{nonce}' ; style-src 'self' 'nonce-{nonce}' ;" />



    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="data:image/x-icon;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAdCAYAAAC9pNwMAAAD0klEQVR42rXWf0iTeRzA8VVqEB2VXD+g4Ojujy76Z7Z/cobtyoPKze5uLjGvWFRz5SKtOEU579nOIGGbbO2HzyzHptP2UG2mzUJz6UCmFDGjgoFBXBIUQlw7gmP2vc8TZ/f03WfpORy8/9r3eV58nt8i0Ry/gi3NX+wSW15B01SPRYv5+y7PugsQklKe5eaiwjKx5Xwa+FfhOqcBGQBF0HO37yk9uFvzXo5vMffy7pCLzt+LcS/3Ch42+xOe/fwwrv5kMK9xRdhcLdz5ziVtbrgn9AU8IadIEH/Gs2o6+KCnl7GUCErrzE7Wqo6ils0AVJaj29GX/OlCvajRhcIXefqD8dOIfCVcHGjGFAhjH40H63GJCrGFyvC+zL7CMenliA/InACbi4cuCQTiLwzG/aG+sygn8uubIFkOmUSty3mRout+F08DVA01QP/4/xD6b/GOriceyKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
    <style type="text/css" nonce="{nonce}">
        body {
            background-color: #e9ebee;
            /*background-color: transparent1;
            background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABQYAAAKfCAIAAACzD4L/AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvDQ0NDQ0OvlCYkHhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGnqlNCHx0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0CulCYmHhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGXilNSDw0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDT0Kum///3/AVhVzNadZFJsAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
       
[Edited for brevity...]

        .logo-img {
            width: 128px;
            height: 128px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <app-root ngCspNonce="{nonce}">
        <div id="pre-bootstrap">
            <div class="messaging">
                <img class="mp-login-img" alt="MHK MarketProminence Logo" src="data: image/png; base64, /h0Jb39y87b+4t4ckcGtq1LQX57qhFAqGlMhzVVVVX+XO9jmihl2XS5ExO8P5UDMTZ3AnIUKEOBRQ1GvG8oGnzlQqqXzprFNn4TmXe5kVQyvaa86vWq5UUPkSphjJnwcvMG74H+5tweTLb194HRtVqRVVPgT3E8esn829LLipfefhpIweumnZI0ollQ9hVAZauWh7nHt7yMIwqo/ScHOtQoEZ3K91Jqq8pUJ+/kQllDw+f1WM1J0Zhdh983vJ1bQX4up07CJPpOor5lqycuCgr+P4T7oK92RlO0AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <h3 class="loading-text">
                    Loading, please stand by...
                </h3>
                <br />
                <img class="logo-img"
                     alt="loading..."
                     src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhMAEsAQAAACH/C05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwEAAAAh+QQBAAAZACwAAAAAMAEsAYQAAACtos+vpc+upc2upM+wptGvpM+qn8qro8uto8+upc+vpdCfj7+vpNCso8+nn8etpM+OcaqLdLmHgLiGebmAgLiLfruAQICOfbUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAF/2AmjmRpnmiqrmzrvnAsz3Rt33iu7FDYCJZvB0TonxGX/9TE9d0KjhXAtJWHoyU9AlkxheYhdaFU4hKLPY5J4lJc+U2JZRZCXx3/xoW6WVFx05XwEpII0C0Iu9VR2ZDZs9l9mQ6LLUJ1k6TTf6IR4u3WR3cmZRXVAWcihBamFDUdd58twQTqnCASmWEl1AAAA7" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </app-root>
</body>
</html>


